# Weird windowed resolution - can't seem to change without changing the name

Tags: unity, resolution

My game is windowed, and when I set the resolution in the build settings (960x540 - 16:9 - Windows standalone), and build it, it works as intended, but from then on, I can no longer change the resolution (can change it in the editor, and it also saves, but when I build it, it is still the original res (960x540))unless I change the Product Name as well. When I change the product name, I can change the resolution, build it, and it will change, but then it is stuck as well. When I change back to the first name, the resolution automatically change it the resolution for the first name (960x540) (it doesn't show up in the editor, only when you build it.)

So basically:

```
Name1
960x540

Name2
1280x720

Name3
1024x576

etc
```

So you can change the resolution every time you change the name and build it, and that name is stuck with that resolution (no matter what you change it to in the editor later). I am fairly new with unity, so am I missing something very basic here?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, once the project is build, if you target windows platforms you will get a dialog to select the resolution at startup.

This is optionally since you can disable it and create your own mechanism for managing screen resolution at runtime using the provided API [Screen.SetResolution](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen.SetResolution.html).